# How To Merge Duplicate Keys In Multidimensional Array?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code:

```
$data = array ( 
    "2018" => array (   
        "September" => array (  
            "02" => ("Line 1"), 
            "02" => ("Line 11"), 
            "12" => ("Line 2"), 
            "31" => ("Line 3")
        )   
    )
);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
```

As you see there is a duplicate key "02"
For this reason I get this result

```
Array (
    [2018] => Array (
        [September] => Array (
            [02] => Line 11
            [12] => Line 2
            [31] => Line 3
        )
    )
)
```

So the `[02] => Line 1` is missing

I am wondering how I could merge the "02" keys so that it will become something like this:

```
"02" => ("Line 1", "Line 11")
```

My problem is that I generate these arrays from mysql so I need a dynamic code and not something like "if september has "02" twice then ..."

I need something like: `if $year > $month` and a duplicate key, then merge it's values.

Comment: Where do you get array from?

Comment: how do you get data array ?

Comment: You know your first array is incorrect? You can't have the same key twice...

Comment: change your paste to show json strings instead, then we can play with the array ourselves

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_key_exists()` to check if the key already exists before setting it. If it doesn't exist, create an entry for the new key, with the new value in an array of one item. If it does exist, then just add the new value to end of the existing array.

```
// Assume $key is your key and $value is your value.
while (...) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        $array[$key][] = $value; // Append the new value to the existing array.
    } else {
        $array[$key] = [$value]; // Create a new array with the new value in it.
    }
}
```

Edit: I thought that using the array append syntax on an undefined key would generate a warning, but it appears that is not the case, so you can probably just simplify to the following:

```
while (...) {
    $array[$key][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, a little confused on this answer. I did a test, seems you don't need the if block because:  `$array[$key] = [$value];` is the same as just doing `$array[$key][] = $value;` (even if `$array[$key]` is not defined, no warnings/notices)... so really all you need is `$array[$key][] = $value;` as it covers both situations and adds to, or defines, in one go...... ??

Comment: Huh strange, I was positive that doing the array append syntax on a non-existing key generated a warning, but it appears you're correct.

Comment: Well, I am testing on a php 5.6 server.... don't have access to 7.2 right now... so maybe? I too always thought you had to define the array and keys before assigning, until I started doing it in one line and realized no warnings lol. I should really do some tests on 7.2 though.